# DNS Newbie and my site is not resolving. It was working properly yesterday. (I think it may be nameserver issue but not sure)

Tags: domain-name-system, nameserver

My first post here and thank you in advance for taking a look. My website (**bestwaytodothat.com**) is currently not loading. A little bit of background:

I xferred the domain from Name.com to AWS Route 53 about a week ago and updated the nameservers to the AWS nameservers.

**Current nameservers as seen in my AWS Route 53 are:**

1. ns-59.awsdns-07.com.
2. ns-1504.awsdns-60.org.
3. ns-975.awsdns-57.net.
4. ns-1985.awsdns-56.co.uk.

**The current static IP (A Record) of the website is:** 3.227.138.28

The site was working fine yesterday.

**What I have tried so far:**

1. I tried accessing the site through the static IP (spins
   indefinitely).
2. I confirmed with Name.com that the domain is totally
   out of their system.
3. I checked who.is and do see the nameservers are
   still on the Name.com nameservers even though I updated these about
   a week ago to the AWS nameservers. So I am thinking maybe propagation still needs more time? Again though, the site was loading fine yesterday.

Any ideas what may be going on here? DNS is not my forte so I appreciate any help. If any other information would be helpful, please let me know.

Thanks!

Comment: Your DNS looks fine. If the site doesn't connect when using the ip address then you have a server/site problem, not a DNS problem.

Comment: When I first started answering this question, the .com TLD servers still pointed to Name.com servers. But I just checked again and now they point to Route53. You may have just been impatient?

Comment: it can take 3 till 10 days until all dns on earth have updated... did you just waiting 3 till 10 minutes?